# Can you get a static shock in a vacuum if you are not touch the object?

Tags: electrostatics

For example when you hop on a trampoline sometimes you will be shocked before you even touch the tramp. Does the shock have to pass through the air to get to you or can it work in a vacuum?

Comment: May I invite you to close some of your 23 open questions :)

Comment: You can close questions?? Sorry I'm noob

Comment: @RayKay: Lemon means that if you consider a question to be satisfactorily answered you should click on the tick symbol to accept the answer you like best. This flags the question as *answered*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, electric discharge will also work in vacuum. Think of vacuum tubes.

However, you will not have the [avalance effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_avalanche) of ionized gas like a spark.